# Como excluir opciones de foreign keys en Django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

estoy haciendo un proyecto en Django para mi portfolio que consta en una app bancaria con transacciones sencillas. Cada uno de los modelos de las diferentes transacciones (depósitos, extracciones, transferencias, etc) tiene asignado una ForeignKey de una cuenta bancaria (en el caso de las transferencias, tiene asignado 2 cuentas bancarias). El problema es que cuando por ejemplo, quiero hacer un depósito, en el dropdown de la app, me aparecen las cuentas bancarias de todos los usuarios, cuando deberían aparecer solo las cuentas bancarias del usuario logueado. ¿Alguien sabe como solucionar esto? ¿Existe alguna forma de filtrar los objetos en el form? Ahora les muestro parte de mi código para que puedan verlo, y mostrarles las soluciones que intenté. Muchas gracias desde ya y saludos desde Argentina!

Model:

```
class Deposit(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    account = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Form:

```
class DepositForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # def __init__(self, account,  *args, **kwargs):
    #         super(DepositForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #         self.fields['account'].queryset = account

    class Meta:
        model = Deposit
        fields = "__all__"
```

Views:

```
def transactions_deposit(request):
    form = DepositForm()#account=BankAccount.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id))
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'transactions_deposit.html', context)

def transactions_depositsave(request):
    form = DepositForm(request.POST)
    bankaccount = BankAccount.objects.get(account_number=request.POST["account"])
    amount = request.POST["amount"]
    amount = Decimal(amount)
    bankaccount.balance += amount
    bankaccount.save()
    context = {
        "bankaccount": bankaccount,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return render(request, 'bankaccounts_detail.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'bankaccounts_detail.html', context)
```

**Aclaración**: El código que aparece comentado fue la solución que intenté implementar, la cual funciona parcialmente, ya que efectivamente en el dropdown me muestra solo las cuentas bancarias del usuario logueado, pero no me permite hacer el save dándome el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError at /transactions/deposit/save/

'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: En la vista de transactrions_deposit, cuando intentaste con la línea comentada agregaste: form = DepositForm(instance=account) para filtrar? Que sería lo mismo que form = DepositForm(instance=BankAccount.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id))

Comment: Hola cristian gracias por responder, cuando intento poner `form = DepositForm(instance=account)` no tiene de donde exportar el account, me dice que no esta definido. Porque crees que esos 2 codigos serian lo mismo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es pasar el request al formulario de esta manera:

```
def transactions_deposit(request):
    form = DepositForm(request=request)
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'transactions_deposit.html', context)
```

Posteriormente usas ese request para filtrar el queryset:

```
class DepositForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Extraer el request pasado desde el form
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        super(DepositForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Por defecto el queryset debe estar vacio
        self.fields["account"].queryset = BankAccount.objects.none()
        if self.request:
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                # si el request no es vacio y el usuario esta logeado, obtener el id del usuario y filtrar el queryset
                self.fields["account"].queryset = BankAccount.objects.filter(user__id=self.request.user.id)
                
    class Meta:
        model = Deposit
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias !! me sirvio funciona perfecto!

Comment: tu codigo funciona perfecto para filtrar las cuentas, pero no me deja validar el formulario, si pongo print(form.errors) consigo lo siguiente en la consola <ul class="errorlist"><li>account<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>